# dropdownlist value: converting from string to int then back to string and display in textbox

Tags: c#, string, drop-down-menu, integer, selectedvalue

I have multiple dropdown lists. I'm trying to have dropdown list input values to be added together and that the answer be displayed in a textbox. I'm converting the values into integers for the arithmetic operations and then back into strings to display the answer in the textbox.

It builds without errors in Visual Studio and when loaded in the browser. But when you select one dropdownlist an error will occur: "Input string was not in the correct format." For the life of me I can't find the error with the code:

displayRed is the Textbox i want the answer to be displayed in
Red1DD, Red2DD etc. are the dropdownlists.

```
displayRed.Text =
  (Convert.ToInt32(Red1DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red2DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red4DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red8DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red16DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red32DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red64DD.SelectedValue.ToString())
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red128DD.SelectedValue.ToString())).ToString();
```

this is what one of the dropdownlists look like:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Red1DD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="red_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" Text="--" />
        <asp:ListItem value="0" Text="0" />
        <asp:ListItem value="1" Text="1" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Are your dropdownlists initialized with an integer value when you first open the page?

Comment: How are you dropdownlists being databound?

Comment: Why not just set a `List<int>` as `DataSource` for combos then use `(int)SelectedItem` for arithmetic then `ToString()` on final result?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="Red1DD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="red_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" Text="--" />
            <asp:ListItem value="0" Text="0" />
            <asp:ListItem value="1" Text="1" />

Comment: No my dropdownlists are not initialized with an integer value when you first open the page. There's an initial "--" option with a value of "". So nothing. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `Red1DD.SelectedItem.Text;` instead of `SelectedValue.ToString()`

```
displayRed.Text =
  (Convert.ToInt32(Red1DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red2DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red4DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red8DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red16DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red32DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red64DD.SelectedItem.Text)
 + Convert.ToInt32(Red128DD.SelectedItem.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: Selected value and text are totally different...SelectedItem.Text only give you text that is displayed not the value of item

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is, that you define a default value of empty string for each of your dropdowns. 
`<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="" Text="--" />`

Now when you change the selection of one of the dropdowns to 0 or 1, then the values of the other dropdowns are still empty strings. 
`Convert.ToInt32(..)` does not like an empty string as argument an throws an Exception.

Therfore change your default value to 0/1 or you have to handle empty strings in your "convert logic". 
For example `Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Red1DD.SelectedValue.ToString()) ? "0" : Red1DD.SelectedValue.ToString());`
and so on.

(You can create a method, which checks if the string is empty and returns the parsed value or zero if emtpy.)